# TypeError for scipy.special.hyp1f1

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I'm currently working on a project involving confluent hypergeometric functions and I trie dto implement my existing code in Python with the help of scipys special functions. When I try to run the code, I get the following error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'hyp1f1' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Googling turned up a post where the user tried to call symbolic values, but this is not the case. I do however have complex arguments. Is this an issue for the implementation of these functions?

The problematic code reads 
`special.hyp1f1(g(k,zeta)+1-1j*y(En,m,zeta),2*g(k,zeta)+1,-2*1j*p(En,m)*r)`, where g,y, and p are real functions.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, scipy's confluent hypergeometric function `hyp1f1(a,b,x)` only allows real parameters. [Documentation](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.special.hyp1f1.html)

> Parameters:    a, b:array_like
>
> ```
>    Real parameters
> ```
>
> x:array_like
>
> ```
>    Real or complex argument
> ```